# Where does mycelium growing in wood get oxygen?

Tags: mycology

As per title, where does mycelium, growing in wood, get its oxygen? I mean when the mycelium is spreading into wood, say an old log, beneath the surface.

As an example, say I put mushroom dowels into a log, and seal it over with wax - standard way of doing it. Where is the sealed off mycelium getting it's oxygen ?

Comment: Hi Jimmy. What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by out community. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, yeah fair enough. I didn't really know where to start on this question, I did some googling but didn't find anything. This stack exchange question turns up on the first page of google search so I think maybe not many people have discussed this point online.

Comment: they need an aerobic environment, they absorb oxygen from water or from there air. mycelium are cells and have a cytoplasmic membrane, which can absorb oxygen the same as other eukariotes.